# Does apple delete core data on the app update from itunes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using sqlite in the first version of my app to store some data, now I have to change the structure for some tables.

Note that I released new version before and notice that the database was deleted after update since I did not see the database records after update and it start registering rows again.

My question is do I need to handle the tables deletion on update, and why apple delete the tables in the previous update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the name of your database file, table name and the location.

From Apple's programming guide:
When a user downloads an app update, iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:

```
<Application_Home>/Documents
<Application_Home>/Library
```

Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely on them being present after an update.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

Comment: NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
    
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"places.db"]];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) {const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &placesDB) == SQLITE_OK) { //create the DB}

Comment: the above is my code to create the DB, as understand my DB will not remove on update, is this true consumption ?

Comment: It looks fine. You are creating the DB in the documents directory only. Did you change the db name, table name or the table structure in the update?

Comment: I changed the table structure in the update but the DB name still the same

Comment: @OmarFreewan That could be the problem. But as Apple's documentation states, you cannot rely on this.

`Ref: Although files in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely on them being present after an update.` It is better to keep a server store such as syncing important user data up to iCloud.

Comment: OK so I should backup my data to iCloud and at the new release restore them

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons why you did not see any data after the update. For example, the code in your second update could have changed the name of the database file, or the names of certain tables or fields.

In principle, the old sqlite store should be present after the update.

You will have to code the migration manually: on first launch after the update, create a new store, read every record from the old store and save it with the new format in the new store.